# dropTA specific indicator by name

Tags: r, quantmod

Can't figure out how to delete a specified indicator by name from TA list in R quantmod.

```
require("quantmod")
getSymbols("AAPL", src="yahoo", from = '2018-01-1', to = '2019-01-1')
#my custom indicator
AAPL_sma_50 <- SMA(
 Cl(AAPL),
 n = 50
)
candleChart(AAPL, up.col = "black", dn.col = "red", theme = "white")
addTA(AAPL_sma_50, on = 1, col = "blue")
addBBands()
listTA()
```

`listTA()` output:

> [[1]] addVo()
>
> [[2]] addTA(ta = AAPL_sma_50, on = 1, col = "blue")
>
> [[3]] addBBands()

I'm able to do delete built-in with `dropTA('addBBands')`, but cannot delete custom indicator the same way:

```
dropTA('AAPL_sma_50')
Error in dropTA("AAPL_sma_50") : nothing to remove
```

> dropTA(2) is not working by index either - it always deletes first element

How I can delete the second custom one only, or how to create it, to be able to delete later by name- e.g. `dropTA('myCustomIndicator')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options to remove TA's from the plot. The trick is to know that when you use `addTA(my_indicator)`, you can not use `dropTA(my_indicator)`. Because you added the TA via `addTA()`, so you need to call `dropTA(ta = "addTA")`.

Now a few possibilies:

```
dropTA(all = TRUE) # removes all technical indicators
dropTA(ta = "addBBAnds") # removes the bolinger bands you added via addBBands()
```

If you added a few custom TA's with addTA, you can specify which version to delete if you now the order.

```
dropTA(ta = "addTA", occ = 2) # removes the second occurence of the TA you added
dropTA(ta = "addTA", all = TRUE) # removes all TA's added with addTA
```

This is useful when you have used multiple addEMA or addSMA indicators to the chart.

example with EMA indicators:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL", src="yahoo", from = '2018-01-1', to = '2019-01-1')

candleChart(AAPL, up.col = "black", dn.col = "red", theme = "white")
addEMA(Cl(AAPL), n = 13, on = 1)
addEMA(Cl(AAPL), n = 21, on = 1)
addEMA(Cl(AAPL), n = 5, on = 1)

dropTA(ta = "addEMA", occ = 2) # removes the second occurence of the EMA's you added
dropTA(ta = "addEMA", all = TRUE) # removes all (other) EMA's added
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! I tried with occ param before and failed, but my error was I thought occ is index. It is addTA occurence Instead as it name suggests :)